# SQL tracking changes

Tags: sql-server, audit-trail, audit-tables

Hi i have a view that contains:

```
ITEMID ITEMNAME STATUS
1001    BRICKS   1
```

And the table is updatated to:

```
ITEMID ITEMNAME STATUS
1001    BRICKS1111   1
```

and i want that status automaticaly would change to 0 when update/insert is made (it can be made from ERP software)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: [Database triggers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger)

Comment: If you are using MSSQL you can do this with a trigger:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Comment: Yes its mssql, i'll read about triggers. Thank you!